# Java SSH Time Out

Tags: java, terminal, timeout

With "ssh pi@IP-Addresse" I can connect to my Raspberry via Terminal(cmd).
In my java code I used the command :

Process conc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh pi@ IP");

So it tries to connect via SSH.
But I have no idea how to deal with no answer, like there is no timeout. So what I need is something like an interruption or timeout after a few seconds with no answer.
Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Try a library that connects via ssh, like ssh4j, youll have more control.
You could also read the standard IO of that process, and just wait for the "connection timed out" or "host unreachable" message, etc

Comment: Thank you. I will try.